# Making jenkins plugin - change context path

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I am developing jenkins plugin on Netbeans. My question is - how can I change jenkin's contextPath when I run my project in Netbeans or command line?

It always gets deployed to http://localdomain.com:8080/jenkins, and I need it to be deployed to root (http://localdomain.com:8080).

No matter whan I am doing, I always see

> Context path = /jenkins

in Netbeans log.

Besides, I cannot make it work via command line as well. This command

> mvn hpi:run -Dhpi.prefix=/lol

has no effect.

Comment: Got an answer from jenkinsci-dev, that "jenkins" prefix was added intentionally. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-dev/IKp-MKILM1Y/V70oi_B1u7QJ

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://jenkins-ci.org/maven-hpi-plugin/run-mojo.html), default is /, hence don't give any config and try. Also ensure maven-hpi-plugin 1.65 or later (used by parent POM 1.401 or later).

Comment: I have maven-hpi-plugin 1.95. Could you elaborate "dont give any config"? Where I can check if any configs are used?

Comment: `mvn clean package hpi:run`